# How to check a database connection with the given credentials from the controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, controller, database-connection

Can I check if a mysql connection can be established with the given credentials from the controller?(i.e. host, username, pwd etc.)

Please note that I am not talking about setting my rails database.

I have a create form which returns some database credentials and I need to check if such connection exists before storing it in my database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mysql2 module, then trying to open a new connection:

```
require 'mysql2'

conn = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => 'localhost', :username => 'user', :password => 'password', :port => '1111', :database => 'database_name')
```

Read more documentation here: https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2

Comment: You have some syntax errors. Please correct them for the people who might use this and I will acccept your answer.  
      my = Mysql::new("host", "username", "password", "dbname") is the way to go.

Comment: I've fixed the errors, but the way to go is Mysql2::Client.new, isn't it?

Comment: @Sammy, Mysql::new would be right if you're using mysql gem, but I think it's always better to use mysql2 gem because it's faster and have more features.